Should a single person handle communication between team and external entities?
We are a development team dealing with highly technical and critical for society application that has frequent communication with external companies and organizations. Are there any best or common practices with this regards. Should the whole team communicate, or the job should be allocated to single member functioning as a key account. My impression is that often there are only few members of the other companies openly communicating , but all others on a CC. Are there any practices reviewing these patterns. What what are the pros and cons of a single communicator vs all team members comunicate with external companies.

This would depend on a lot of context - what needs to be communicated on what level, what is the education level of both sides and the PR experience, what is the potential public exposure, how sensitive is your public image, how sensitive is your data, how much do you trust the external entity, how much do you trust your own employees to follow any guide laid out, how complicated is your contract, lows or other external rules guiding your communication?

I'm assuming that the word 'single' means one and not a person without a partner, in this context?

Generally it is best to have one point person, to make sure a consistent message is being delivered. However, you should have someone else in the loop as backup, under the *bus factor" rationale.

To add to this answer - if there is a need for multi-level communication, have a single point that matches the level (with a backup for vacations, bus factor, etc.). For example: Product Manager to Client Business Lead, your Deployment Project Manager to their IT Project Manager, etc.

That depends a bit on the relationship and the types of communication but in general it's a good idea to have a single "owner". That owner is the first point of contact and often has a counterpart at the other entity. Together they can figure out how to best handle the communication tasks.
This often involves "delegating": for example if the schematic engineers of your company need to regularly talk to the PCB layout engineers at the other company, you set up a direct pipe but the owners will typically be on CC and have access to all documents and communication being exchanged.

I agree that having a single point of contact is a Good Thing™ as that person sees the overall picture.  And as per @Hilmar even if the point person delegates direct communications to other people, as long as the point person is cc'ed, then they still are being kept in the loop.
But .. (and here is the but), I've experienced teams where the point person dictates that all communications must past through them.  There. Shall. Be. No. Direct. Communications.
This results in people like me sending my questions to the point person.  The point person then re-writes my questions before sending them on to the external party (with me being cc'ed).  So communications become a game of telephone, and I get frustrated as I can see that the re-written question lacks nuances from my original question, and doesn't ask exactly what I wanted to ask.

Before asking whether there are solutions, it might be better to identify whether there are any problems?
What are the topics of the communications, and are they technically and intellectually complicated like academic correspondence, or are they fairly routine things suitable for delegation?
What are the commercial implications - are there any financial risks or mishaps occuring?
Do the correct correspondents find each other easily - initially, and on an ongoing basis (for example, are multiple people messaged because the sender doesn't know who is dealing with the matter that day)?
Is there trouble during ordinary absences? Does the correspondence need routine organising and filing, so others can step in and follow what's going on?
Are people corresponding about matters which are highly personal to their own work activity, or are they all taking turns to correspond as functionaries on behalf of a collective (such as their team, or the wider organisation)?
You definitely shouldn't attempt to reorganise your company's existing communication patterns, if you're not attuned to them and competent to detect and articulate the problems with them in the first place.
The best approach to complicated practices where you don't already know there is a problem (or already know from experience there is going to be a problem, and what its correct solution is), is to let things find their own level first and then start fixing specific problems as you identify them and as others acknowledge the problem and your proposed solution.
Adopting lists of "best practices" just leads to mindless complexity and an absence of understanding amongst those dictating what is supposedly best, especially because different companies and different teams within companies, can be dealing with things at very different scales, and what is necessary in a large organisation can be ridiculous overhead or totally dysfunctional in a small one.

There is no general one size fits all rule to this very general issue. Often a single point of contact can make sense. However, the degree that this single point of contact is enforced, whether this is a one or two way contact and how that contact is shaped can vary strongly. And sometimes it doesn't make sense (or only at certain stages).
For instance, it can make sense to have a single point of communication that goes both ways, one person that knows what is communicated to the external party, what was agreed upon and what the contract is. A very natural and simple example for this is a team lead ordering pizza for the team. Usually they collect all the food wishes, order the pizza, handle any questions about the location the delivery person might have and they will be handling the payment and handover of the food. This keeps things simple for the outside communication and avoids any confusion.
On the other hand, the single point of contact might just be for incoming requests that then get redirected to a domain matter expert. And even further, a single point of contact could not be a single person for every contact but the same for the same request or just the same phone number/mail address etc. for externals to use every time. An simple everyday life example would be call centres. Or a team lead taking calls from a client and then potentially redirecting the call to the expert 3rd, 2nd or 1st level support handler of the respective tool the inquiry is about. It could also be between two teams that develop adjacent software, where only the overall architecture and API needs synchronization, such that two system architects talk to each other and then document and break down any agreements for their internal colleagues, so those can focus on the internal details. This would be similar to a 'regular' architect collecting all information from clients how to build a house, drawing the plans and then handing them over to their actual house builders (sorry, not an expert in that area, so I'm just making this process up^^).
Then again, in some scenarios such a single point makes no sense. If you hire a contracting company to work really close together with you, be it to provide additional workers building the foundation of a house or more developers to create a software together with your team, where they are mostly integrated into your team or work together on low level features, a single point of communication is just a huge bottleneck and it is more reasonable to have individual workers talk about their individual issues one-to-one.
What is the best approach in a concrete case, depends on a lot of context:

what needs to be communicated on what level
how much communication do you assume is necessary and at what stages
how quick a turnaround do you need to have (how long can it take to answer a question)
how important is it that every question is answered absolutely correctly
which way will communication likely be initiated, always from one direction into the other or would it be two way
what is the education level of both sides and the communication skills (can your Chinese employees talk to your Brazilian contractors)
what is the PR experience, what is the potential public exposure, how sensitive is your public image, how sensitive is your data, how much do you trust the external entity, how much do you trust your own employees to follow any guide laid out, how complicated is your contract, laws or other external rules guiding your communication (e.g. would it be a problem if your low level non-native speaker 'accidentally' calls the female executive a hot biatch or your junior developer gets quoted considering just hardcoding the credentials for now)
what happens if that one person is not available
do you need to protect trade secrets
what are the time zones, does it make sense to have everyone up at night to answer calls
what are potential side-goals that you want to achieve in your communication, e.g. do you want to try and upsell a product on the side when answering questions, expand a contract or otherwise oil some gears in a certain direction; or perhaps find out whether the individuals work and communicate well together as you might acquire some of the external talent in the future (e.g. buy the contracting company)
and many more...

All in all you need to break down your actual situation and then make a conscious decision about which process likely works best for your case.
So maybe try to refine the question as a new question such that it is more specific to your case (yet general enough to also be helpful for others with a similar case)
